# Discord.py how to add a role to a member

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code witch checks when someone wrights "send @user to court" and then gets the mentioned person id and wrights "sending to court" but im trying too make it add the role "court" but it doesent work heres the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import ctx

class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
       print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            if re.search("^send.*court$", messageContent):
                user_id = message.mentions[0].id
                await message.channel.send('sending to court!')
                role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="court")
                await client.add_roles(user_id, role)

client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: `wrights`? *rights*? *writes*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can also use `message.content` directly in `len()` and `re.search()` (if you don't need it later again)
2. For `re.search()` you have to import `re`
3. You haven't got a variable `server` so you can't use it in `server.roles` as python can't get the server just from nothing
4. (Main Problem) It's not `client.add_roles`, it's [`member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) where you have to use a [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) object

Revised:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import ctx
import re

class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
       print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if len(message.content) > 0:
            if re.search("^send.*court$", message.content):
                user = message.mentions[0]
                await message.channel.send('sending to court!')
                role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="court")
                await user.add_roles(role)

client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: still doesn't work it says "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'"

Comment: So either you did not mention a person or you did it a wrong way, can't explain that another way.. Or maybe just update discord.py? Found no version since this would be in but maybe that's the problem‍♂️ Just for explanation; this Attribute Error means, it didn't find any user/mention in the message

Comment: Iv changed a couple stuff and it fixed it thanks

Comment: You're welcome, just don't forget to mark it as right or if you changed too much write your own answer and mark it as right